# JTable column identifiers not showing when table added to scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, defaulttablemodel

I have a JScrollPane as a private field initialised using its default constructor. This pane is supposed to dynamically add a new table and fill it when a row in another table is selected.

The table adds row data fine and is displayed but the column identifiers don't show up. There is a list selection listener setup on the table with rows being selected and that is being called fine as well.

scrollForeign is the preinitalised scrollpane and tableMain is the selection table.

Code below:

```
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent s) {
    if (s.getSource().equals(tableMain.getSelectionModel())) {
        int caseNo;

        DefaultTableModel jobsModel = new DefaultTableModel(0,0);
        JTable tableJobs = new JTable();
        scrollForeign.add(tableJobs);

        jobsModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"jid", "name", "price", "description", "quantity"});
        tableJobs.setModel(jobsModel);
        jobsModel.setRowCount(0);

        jobsModel.addRow(new String[] {"1", "test", "10", "test", "1"});
        jobsModel.addRow(new String[] {"2", "test", "10", "test", "1"});
        jobsModel.addRow(new String[] {"3", "test", "10", "test", "1"});
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `JScrollPane#add`, use [`JScrollPane#setViewportView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView(java.awt.Component)) instead

On the other hand, don't create a new `JTable` each time, simply create the model and apply it to the same instance of `JTable` each time...

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent s) {
    if (s.getSource().equals(tableMain.getSelectionModel())) {
        int caseNo;

        DefaultTableModel jobsModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"jid", "name", "price", "description", "quantity"},0);

        jobsModel.addRow(new String[] {"1", "test", "10", "test", "1"});
        jobsModel.addRow(new String[] {"2", "test", "10", "test", "1"});
        jobsModel.addRow(new String[] {"3", "test", "10", "test", "1"});

        tableJobs.setModel(jobsModel);
    }
}
```

Where `tableJobs` is a instance field and has already been applied to the `JScrollPane`...

Comment: Would setviewportview work if I wanted to display multiple tables at once in that scrollpane?

Comment: No, you can't do that, if you want the headers, each table would need to be in it's own scrollpane